# Question score goes crazy

Tags: bug, voting

I was voting on a question but I was just spamming the vote (on and off) just to see if there was a bug. Actually there is. After spamming the vote on and off for about 10 seconds, stop and watch the score change like crazy (not due to someone else doing the same thing). When the craziness stops, the score will return to normal.

So can we fix this crazy bug?

Steps to reproduce:

- Select your <del>victim</del> question
- Repeat the following as fast as you can for 10 seconds:

  - Click the vote button
  - Click again to undo vote
- Watch the mayhem that happens to the score
- Cast vote if needed

Comment: Is that a my-style bug? 1) It's actually not the way the system is intended to work. 2) pretty sure there was someone else who fooled you.

Comment: No repro when testing in this question... only a "You have voted and undone your vote too many times. Your vote is now locked in" after a while -.-

Comment: @nicael I am not going to try this with any other post,

Comment: Ok, then it was someone else, sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there actually was a second person spam-voting. It's happened before, so it's probably what happened again.